# Using pkrevealcontroller on existing Xcode storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am trying to integrate the pkrevealcontroller sliding menu into an existing iOS project that has an existing storyboard with segues, etc. I extended UINavigationViewController and linked my new class to the Nav Controller on the storyboard. In my app delegate I do the following:

```
MainNavViewController *frontViewController = [[MainNavViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[myRootViewController alloc] init]];
UIViewController *rightViewController = [[menuViewController alloc] init];

self.revealController = [PKRevealController  revealControllerWithFrontViewController:frontViewController
                                                                rightViewController:rightViewController
                                                                            options:nil];

self.window.rootViewController = self.revealController;
```

When I run the application, it successfully adds the sliding menu icon to the navigation bar, and the frontview slides as I want it. But it is not using the title or segues I have added on the storyboard. Is what I'm trying even possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "extended UINavigationViewController"? Where does the PKRevealController come in? Are any of the controllers you mention in your question in the storyboard, or are these new ones you're adding?

Comment: rdelmar - I added the rest of the code from the app delegate. By extended, I mean I created my own custom class that is a subclass of uinavigationviewcontroller. MainNavViewController and myRootViewController are in my storyboard.

Comment: Do you have a FrontViewController or right viewController in your storyboard? I'm trying to figure out what you have in the storyboard, and what new stuff you're adding here in the app delegate.

Comment: I see. The FrontViewController is in the storyboard, as is the MainNavViewController (it's my storyboard's main nav view controller). The rightviewcontroller is being added in the app delegate. The pkrevealer functionality is working great, but my nav view controller is losing the titles and segues I have in the storyboard. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're instantiating a new frontViewController -- that's not the one that's in your storyboard. I'm not exactly sure how to do this, but I would try it like this. I would add a UIViewController in the storyboard -- change its class to PKRevealController, and make it the initial controller in the storyboard, but don't hook it up to the rest of the scenes. Give your MainNavViewController an identifier in IB, then change the code in your app delegate to this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.revealController = (PKRevealController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *rightViewController = [[menuViewController alloc] init];
    MainNavViewController *frontViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"frontViewController"];
    [self.revealController setFrontViewController:frontViewController];
    [self.revealController setRightViewController:rightViewController];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Does it mean I should make `PKRevealController` entry-point of my storyboard ? Can't I just invoke PKRevealController from tab bar button click handler ?

Comment: @ruslan, Do you have a tab bar controller as the root view controller of your window? Do you want to make the PKRevealController one of the controllers in a tab?

Answer (score 0):

My app delegate does not have the `revealController` variable so had to create that manual, is that something you have to do?

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift** use this,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    var frontViewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("frontVC") as! UIViewController

    var leftViewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("leftVC") as! UIViewController

    var revealController:PKRevealController = PKRevealController(frontViewController: frontViewController, leftViewController: leftViewController)

    self.window?.rootViewController = revealController

    return true
}
```