# iOS Integrate PKRevealController with Storyboard & Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, storyboard, viewcontroller

I'm trying to integrate PKRevealController into an existing project of mine.

https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController

How do I set up my left view controller, right view controller, and front view controller if I'm using storyboard? The readme says to do...

```
PKRevealController *revealController = [PKRevealController revealControllerWithFrontViewController:frontVC leftViewController:leftVC options:options];

self.window.rootViewController = revealController;
```

Where would I put these lines of code in my existing storyboard project? Or are there any alternatives to set this up?

Thanks!

Comment: I answered a similar question here: [Using pkRevealController on existing Xcode storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824959/using-pkrevealcontroller-on-existing-xcode-storyboard/14825615#14825615)

Answer (score 2):

Just set the segue destination controller's type to `PKRevealController` and set storyboard ID for front, left and right view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ToMain"]) {

    PKRevealController* prc = segue.destinationViewController;

    prc.frontViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FrontViewController"];
    prc.leftViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftViewController"];
    prc.rightViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RightViewController"];

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Does it mean I should make `PKRevealController` entry-point of my storyboard ? Can't I just invoke PKRevealController from tab bar button click handler ?

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't work. You can set the view controller in IB to have a class of `PKRevealController` but when the segue happens, the screen is blank, just a translucent gray.

Comment: @startupthekid You need at least 5 view controller in the storyboard for my example to work: source view controller (where you put my example code), PKRevealController, front , left and right view controller. For front, left and right you have to set the storyboard IDs

Comment: I have over 20. Still doesn't work. It's a bug in the last version.

Comment: OK. I dont use PKRevealController anymore. Instead I use ECSlidingViewController. Maybe it works better for you, too.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I'm gonna out it here anyways :)

To make **PKRevealController** work with storyboard basically you'll need three view controllers.

1. **BaseController** (i called it that), which get extended by the PKRevealController how's going to act as the base for the Main content controller and Navigation controller.
2. **MainController**, which get set as the fronViewController.
3. **NaviController**, which we basically use as the leftViewController, aka navigation menu.

FYI: You can design and code the MainController and NaviController from the stroyboard.

So this is how we do it;
First we need to extend our BaseController with PKRevealController like this;

```
@interface MainController : PKRevealController
```

Second, still in BaseController, add these line to the viewDidLoad method;

```
//init the fonrViewController
UIViewController *homeController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeScreen"];
//init the leftViewController
UIViewController *naviContrlller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"quickNaviScreen"];

[self setFrontViewController:homeController];
[self setLeftViewController:naviContrlller];
```

Then set the PKRevealController delegate as;

```
self.delegate = self;
```

And that's it.

Comment: Thanks it works ! But how can we show / hide menu left or right without swipe from the front vc ? Plz