# How do I use PKRevealController with storyboards?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have been trying to use PKRevealcontroller with storyboards but can't seem to find a way to integrate it. All I want is to have a main view controller and a menu on the left.

I can't seem to figure out how and where to add code. If someone has an example that would be great.

I want to try using PKRevealcontroller because it seems to be the only one that passes information from one view controller to another.

Comment: Are you just trying to pass data from one ViewController to another?

Comment: OK, that was a dumb question. Have you tried using the `prepareForSegue` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use PKReveal if all you want to do is pass data between segues. The best and simplest way to do this would be to use the `prepareForeSegue` method. The method would look something like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    FirstViewController *transferViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"joeSegue"])
    {
        //the data you would pass goes here...
    }

}
```

For a simple explanation, see [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/).

If you must use PKReveal, here is a [tutorial on how it's done](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDYHFMYoDcU).

Comment: yes i know but i want to have the ability of having a sliding menu thats why i want to use PKreveal

Comment: I guess for now it be usefull to know how can i set up the PKreveal class completely with storyboards

Comment: @XavierSerrano If you want to use PKRevealController, I think you will have to download it from GitHub and implement it. not sure how to do this exactly, but it is explained here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885887/ios-integrate-pkrevealcontroller-with-storyboard-auto-layout. You can achieve a similar sliding effect by using a push segue, not to mention it will be ALOT easier to put in.

Comment: @XavierSerrano. Please makeup your mind as to what you want to do. In your question, you state: "I want to try using PKRevealcontroller because it seems to be the only one that passes information from one view controller to another." And in your comment above, you state: "yes i know but i want to have the ability of having a sliding menu thats why i want to use PKreveal". Which are you going for?

Comment: @XavierSerrano edited my answer to add tutorial for PKReveal.

Comment: thanks! i will check it out. my bad if the question seemed ambiguous.